# std::inserter replacement for C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, inserter

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24774863/3717478):
`set_intersection` uses `std::inserter` as follows:

```
std::set_intersection(
    netSet.begin(), netSet.end(),
    portSet.begin(), portSet.end(),
    std::inserter(result, result.end())
);
```

However, `std::inserter` is no longer available with `C++17` so how should this code be rewritten?

EDIT:  As many have pointed out, std::inserter is still available in C++17.  Somehow I ended up reading how std::iterator had been deprecated not realising that it wasn't referring to std::inserter.  My problem was solved by specifically including the `<iterator>` header in my code.

Comment: Where did you see `std::inserter` will not be available? I don't believe it's removed or even deprecated.

Comment: [It's not deprecated or removed...](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/inserter/)

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of [`std::iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator), which was intended to help provide the `typedef`s needed when creating your own iterators, but was concluded not to be very useful and hence deprecated?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031805/preparation-for-stditerator-being-deprecated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `std::inserter` is no longer available with [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)

That's *not* true!

There is no indication that [`std::inserter`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/inserter/) will be removed from C++17, or that it will become deprecated.

---

> I was getting confused with `std::iterator`

[Preparation for std::iterator Being Deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031805/preparation-for-stditerator-being-deprecated).